# find, update and return an array object inside a document (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a bunch of documents in the following format:

```
{
    _id: "5b38c85f213751038ff4d0bb",
    classes: [
      {
        _id: "5b38c85f21375103ytg65ju7",
        standard: "12",
        numberOfStudents: 45
      },
      {
        _id: "5b38c85f2137510370987hgd",
        standard: "11",
        numberOfStudents: 51
      },
    ]
}
```

**I want to:**

1. Search the collection of documents by the `_id` and a particular class's `_id`.
2. Update the `numberOfStudents` for that class.
3. Return only the class object.

So for `_id: "5b38c85f213751038ff4d0bb"` & `classes._id: "5b38c85f21375103ytg65ju7"`, updating the `numberOfStudents: 43` the result I'm expecting is:

```
{
  _id: "5b38c85f21375103ytg65ju7",
  standard: "12",
  numberOfStudents: 43
}
```

I've tried a couple of things but they all return the whole document but not the way I want it to be.

Comment: what criteria you do have to update `numberOfStudents`?

Comment: It'll be a user defined value so it could be any number. We just have to update it on the basis of the two ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": "5b38c85f213751038ff4d0bb" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "classes": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$classes",
        "as": "class",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [
            "$$class._id",
            "5b38c85f21375103ytg65ju7"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$classes" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$classes" }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "numberOfStudents": { "$literal": 43 },
    "standard": 1
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5b38c85f21375103ytg65ju7",
    "numberOfStudents": 43,
    "standard": "12"
  }
]
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tiZ0_Chdo5h)

Comment: So I went with your approach and it returns a blank array.

Comment: I have given you the **try** section... please have a look

Comment: Yeah thats the strange part that it works on the playground but not on my machine.

Comment: what is your mongodb version ?

Comment: Then it should work and it should work for mongoose as well... I think you are doing a minor mistake somewhere in the code either is could be with database or something else... try to find it

Comment: Ok seems like I was missing the string to object id conversion. But still the update part doesn't work. I'm trying to update the document with a date based field ```createdDate``` with the ```Date.now()``` but that's not happening.

Comment: Hi your above query has been resolved... Please ask a new question if you have further doubts... thank you

Comment: No a part of it hasn't been resolved. ```numberOfStudents``` don't actually update in the database.

Comment: this is an aggregation query it will only return  the document as you want... If you want to update field/column in database then you will have to run an `update` query...